# Displaying unique mathematical properties in a textfield

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there anyway I can display exponents or fractions properly in a textfield.

I'm creating educational software and want to see actual symbols as opposed to: 3/4 or x^2

Answer (score 2):

There should be no problem doing that, just make sure you embedded the ² and ¾ characters.